# Splitting a string by space before delimiter, while keeping it

Tags: java, split

Okay, so I have searched throughout google and this site and have not found a solution that works how I want for this problem. I have a string, for example "javaRegexConfusion" where I want to split by capital letters, while also maintaining them. The problem here is, if I were to split directly by capital letters, one way would leave me without the letters at all, and another I know of would split them into its own object on the array. The result in the string above I want is an array consisting of "java", "Regex", and "Confusion". I am completely unsure of how to go about it. I am sure the solution is extremely simple, however I do not know how to phrase what I am looking for, hence the confusing title.

### EDIT: Found the answer in a totally off topic quest. I am not really familiar with the regexs accepted, and would never have figured out

While I like AlexWien's answer, I prefer this method. Instead of iterating through and then splitting wherever capitals were, the writer of the other answer split right before anything capital.

```
String[] output = input.split("(?=(?!^)[A-Z])");
```

I really like this method and will most likely use this from now on (too bad that I will never remember `"(?=(?!^)[A-Z])")` without looking at it)

Comment: and most people that will read your code using this regex will not understand, too.

Comment: You should add your answer below, i.e. answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer my own yet :(

Answer (score 0):

just iterate through the string, character by character, if you find a char whic `isUpperCase()` then copy to a result string array. store current position, and continue..

Use

```
Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(pos))
```

Comment: Oops, I never even thought of that. I was almost going to work backwards in the string and use `isUpperCase()` to determine the last character in a substring to filter throughout the string, but couldn't quite get it down. Thanks~